# How can I update json empty value in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

When I try to update like below, I received `invalid input syntax for type json. Expected "," or "}"`.

The record's content of problem is `{'open': ','}`.
If the record's content is `{'open': ',abc'}`, I can update correctly like `{'open': 'abc'}`.

```
update hoge SET extra =
REPLACE(
       extra::TEXT,
       extra->>'open',
       regexp_replace(extra->>'open', '^,', '')
)::JSONB
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `JSONB_SET` for update and filter the records that are to be updated in the `where` clause

```
update hoge set extra = jsonb_set(extra, '{open}' ,'"abc"')
  where extra->>'open' = ',abc';
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=10deca42c7ae22fd030f4cb82b4fe23d)